# ValueError while using ember.create_vectorized_features on Ember dataset in Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ember-data

I am using the Ember dataset for a malware detection project in Python. When I try to use the ember.create_vectorized_features() function, I am getting the following error:

ValueError: Samples can not be a single string. The input must be an iterable over iterables of strings.

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to fix it. Can anyone suggest a solution to resolve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaQDx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button. See [code block].

Answer (score 0):

An `issue` [has been opened](https://github.com/elastic/ember/issues/103) on the EMBER project [github repository](https://github.com/elastic/ember).
Follow the issue for a solution or use previous versions of the repository until the issue is resolved.